# How to get Ubuntu Server to act as a Gateway

Tags: networking, server

[Connecting to an Ubuntu Server using Ethernet cables but no internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102068/connecting-to-an-ubuntu-server-using-ethernet-cables-but-no-internet-connection)

Required to be configured is a DHCP server, with the *server itself being the DHCP server* and handing out the IPs to each machine.

Also required is the instructions to set the IP of the ethernet card on the server statically in a manner which it can be used to communicate with other systems as the DHCP server and as a file server.

Answer (score 0):

Static IP configuration should be put in `/etc/network/interfaces`. It is a text file, and the documentation for its format can be read by `man 5 interfaces`. By the looks of it, you probably need to put in there something simple like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.1.2.3
    netmask 255.0.0.0
```

Once done, submit `sudo service networking restart` to make use of the new settings.

For handing out replies to DHCP requests, you need a DHCP server, provided for example by `isc-dhcp-server`, `udhcpd`, `dnsmasq` and possibly other packages. I have used `dnsmasq` with success, and it appears to work satisfactorily even if uplink connection to internet (and real DNS servers) doesn't exist. See a [how-to](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-unattended-ubuntu-network-install-dhcp-server-p2) on the subject, it is rather straight-forward to set up.